# Is it correct to omit "be" verbs and conjunctions when reporting a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, omissibility

Can you say "Actor dead aged 44" instead of elaborately saying "Actor dies at age 44"?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. If this is a headline, then we have a tag [headline-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/headline-english/info) which you could [add to the tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/545155/edit) in your question if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a newspaper headline "ACTOR DEAD AGED 44!". It is not grammatically correct as a sentence or as a clause because there is no verb.

"... actor died, aged 44." could be correct, depending on the preceding context. For example: "Later, the actor died, aged 44."

Comment: I would suggest 'Actor dies...' (as in the original post) is more common as a headline than 'Actor died...' because the news discusses *current events*.